# how to remove blank space of text files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to remove all empty lines from some text file. I can do it with:

`grep '[^[:blank:]]' < file1.dat > file1.dat.nospace`

But I need to do it with n-files in a directory. How can I do it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way:

```
for filename in *.dat; do
  grep '[^[:blank:]]' < $filename > $filename.nospace
done
```

here is a more robust way, one that works in a larger variety of circumstances:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.dat" | while read filename; do
  grep '[^[:blank:]]' < "$filename" > "$filename.nospace"
done
```

here a much faster way (in execution time, but also in typing). this is the way i would actually do it:

```
find *.dat -printf "grep '[^[:blank:]]' < \"%f\" > \"%f.nospace\"\n" | sh
```

here is a more robust version of that:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.dat" -printf "grep '[^[:blank:]]' < \"%f\" > \"%f.nospace\"\n" | sh
```

ps: here's the actual correct grep for nonblank lines:

```
grep -v '^$' < $filename > $filename.nospace
```

Comment: Why `grep` when it can be done using simple `sed` command. See my answer below.

Comment: Notice that this isn't actually checking for blank lines, only if lines start with a blank.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it with `find`

```
find . -name '*.dat' -exec sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' {} +
```

Comment: this doesn't give the requested result — it descends into subdirectories, and renames the originals `.bak` instead of creating new `.nospace`s. but it's a better technique in general, and I benchmarked it as 3x as fast as my answer (3s vs 9s for 7000 files, 73MB total).

Comment: @webb No it doesn't rename files. It just keeps original files with `.bak` extension for the scenario when something goes wrong an OP wants to access original files.

Comment: To prevent descending into sub-directories we can just add `-maxdepth 1` option in `find`

Answer (score 1):

this oneliner could probably help you:

```
for a in /path/to/file_pattern*; do sed "/^\s*$/d" $a > $a.nospace;done
```